# RegEx for <title> with leading, trailing, linebreak

Tags: html, regex

Most website I can parse its title easily with RegEx "(.*)"  or "\s*(.+?)\s*".   However some sites have a bit different formatting, like http://www.youtube.com (see below).   The expression above does not work.  Any help catching this kind of format and any other HTML formats?

Thanks
-Tim.

```
<title>
  YouTube - Broadcast Yourself.
```

Comment: @Pumbaa80, I didn't notice there was no language, LOL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/109696

Comment: forgot to set the multiline option on the parser.  Now everything works. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include the line break to the regular expression, in most cases you would only need to use the `\n` inside the expression. That said, which language/interpreter are you using? Some of them doesn't allow multiline expressions.

If they are permitted, something like `(.|\n|\r)*` would suffice.

In case your language or interpreter is not compatible to multiline regular expressions, you could always replace the newlines characters with spaces, and then pass the resulting string to the regular expression parser. That again also depends on your programming environment.

Hope helped!

Comment: I like `[\S\s]` better than `(.|\n|\r)` to match any single character no matter what the `DOTALL` flag is set to, but maybe that's just me

Comment: Felix, thanks for reminding me to set the multi-line option. My original expression actually works when I set multi-line option, when this option is set.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to get this done. For only title, [SIMPLEHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is more than enough.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.youtube.com/');
$title = $html -> find("title") -> innerHTML;
echo $title;
```

Comment: +1. In other words: don't use regex for things it wasn't made for. Seriously, guys, it's not a hard rule.